# mysql count unique grouped items in a table

Tags: mysql

I am sure this is simple but I am getting in a mess with it.

I have a table which is the items in a purchase order. Amongst other things the table has the following fields and an entry for each item:

```
entry
partno
PO
```

`PO`s may have many different parts, with a variable quantity of each.

What I want to have is a query which will return the `PartNo` for a particular `PO` and the count of the number of items of the `partno`.

Comment: I'm thinking `SELECT count(entry), partno, PO FROM items WHERE PO = <particular_PO> GROUP BY partno, PO` but I guess it's more complicated than that? Can you give us examples of the sort of data you want to retrieve? And what SQL code have you tried?

Comment: show us what u tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT partno, COUNT(entry)
FROM table_name
WHERE PO = 'specific_PO'
GROUP BY partno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(partno)  // counting number or partno for particular PO
FROM table
WHERE PO = 'PO_NAME' // for specific PO
GROUP BY partno;   // grouping by PARTNO
```